# Disable default unity editor behaviour on input

Tags: unity

I'm creating a tool to create scenes easier on edition mode. I'm using the right click to delete elements, and I'd like to be able to delete several elements by keeping the right mouse button pressed and moving the mouse around.

The issue is that when I keep the right mouse button pressed over the scene window, the Hand Tool automatically activates, making the camera pan as I move the mouse.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: Maybe the "Custom Editor Tools" will provide you with the means you need to accomplish this. Available from 2019.1.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!
You can make an event not reach the default Unity behaviour by consuming the event with:

```
Event.current.Use();
```

So to avoid camera panning with the right click you can just do:

```
if (e.isMouse && e.type == EventType.MouseDrag && e.button == 1)
{
    Event.current.Use();
}
```